# Import files using Seleliu

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I made the code below and he's working okay. However, I'd like to know how I do so there's a range between dates, example:

[Inside this link](http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-enUS.asp?Data=11/22/2017&Data1=20171122&slcTaxa=APR#):

I'd like to enter a date range:

Date1: 01.01.2020

to

Date2: 30.01.2020

So that he could download the files normally.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

preferences = {"download.defaultt_directory":  "/Users/denisraphael/Desktop/teste", "safebrowsing.enabled": "false"}

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get("http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-enUS.asp?Data=11/22/2017&Data1=20171122&slcTaxa=APR#")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/form/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/p/a").click()
```

Tks!

Comment: How can we set the two dates `Date1: 01.01.2020` and `Date2: 30.01.2020`?

Comment: _italic_ I would like to enter these dates for me to inform the extraction period within the html.
But I'm not getting it. This way works in directories. @DebanjanB

Comment: I think it would be something to this idea.

'sel.type("StartDate", "5/1/2011")'
'sel.type("EndDate", "5/30/2011")'
'sel.click("button1")'

Comment: like this ["http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/boletim1/TxRef1.asp?Data=", data_input, "&Data1=20190311&slcTaxa=PRE", sep = ""] Very tks